# Unable to read excel file - getting ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read an excel file in Python. When I try and `import` the correct module, it doesn't work.

My code is:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
type(wb)
```

and I get this error:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Looks like `xlrd` that you're trying to import `open_workbook` from does not exist/is not installed.

Comment: I am using excel 2016, do you know how to install it?

Comment: Apart from the `ModuleNotFoundError`, you appear to be (trying to) import  `xlrd` but then on the next line, using a different module altogether, `openpyxl`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `xlrd` is not found/does not exist for the instance of Python you're using.

Assuming you're using Python3, you'll want to use pip3 to get modules that aren't already available. Install Python 3's pip with

`sudo aptget install python3-pip`
Then install packages with `pip3 install xlrd`

If you're using Python2, follow the directions from Adam and do `pip install xlrd`

Comment: where do i type that?

Comment: Are you using Windows, MacOS, or Linux? Mac/Linux open a terminal session and type it. I'm not familiar with Windows, but this could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: yeh i am using windows

Comment: Follow the instructions from the link I provided you, then enter `pip install xlrd`.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing into the cmd prompt or terminal:

```
python -c "import xlrd; print xlrd.__VERSION__"
```

If that fails try using pip to install it.

```
pip install xlrd
```

you can try the first step again to check that it's worked

Comment: where do i type this?

Comment: if you're on windows, open up a command prompt. and try typing it in there. you can get to it through the start menu, or by pressing `windows + R` and then typing `cmd` into the window that pops up

Comment: if you can't use pip, it might not be installed. go to their site https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ and it should talk you through getting installed.

Comment: which part? `windows + R`?

Comment: yeh it does not do anything

Comment: if you have the cmd prompt up, does typing `python` and then hitting enter do anything? it should start a command line python session

Comment: it say " 'python' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: this might sound stupid, but do you have python installed?

Comment: yes i do, I will try uninstalling it and installing it again

Comment: try having a look at a pre-packaged distribution called `anaconda`. it comes with a tonne of useful packages and i believe xlrd is included in that. https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: well it installs python, but with a lot of the additional libraries that people commonly use. my thinking was that if you're planning to re-install it, you might as well go straight in with that

Comment: No worries, had any luck?

Comment: its just downloading it now